# How to move a Linux installation to a larger disk with a different partition scheme?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, migration

I decided to make a small Arch Linux USB flash drive to carry around when I need Linux. So I successfully installed it on an awful 8GB flash drive with 5GB on `/` and 3GB on `/home`.

I would like to do this properly now that I have it working so I ordered a [PNY Turbo 128GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive (P-FD128TBOP-GE)](https://www.pny.com/turbo_3_0_usb_flash_drive) and want to move the installation to this new drive.

I also decided to go to a single partition so I don’t end up with one being full and the other not. How can I go about moving the installation to the new drive and switching to one main partition?

Answer (score 1):

Having a secondary distribution is essential.

1. You would boot off a live fdd or whatever to get into a running
   linux environment.
2. Format the entire new flash drive as ext4 or your preferred fstype.
3. Make a folder: /transfer.
4. Mount your old fdd's / in /transfer/old
5. Mount old fdd's /home in /transfer/old/home
6. Mount new fdd in /transfer/new
7. Cd to /transfer
8. Copy everything in old to new(keeping permissions might be smart)

To recap:

```
whoami #should give root
cd /
mkdir transfer
cd transfer
mkdir -p old new
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1 #replace ext4 with preferred fstype
mount /dev/sdb1 /transfer/old #old root partition
mount /dev/sdb2 /transfer/old/home #old home partition
mount /dev/sdc1 /transfer/new #new fdd
cp -rfv --preserve=all old/* new/ #r:copy recurring,f: force copy, v: be verbose
umount /transfer/*
shutdown -rf now #remove live distro and enjoy new fdd
```